# Apply function for all values of an array

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm using a custom query with a multi-select parameter as Datasource in DataStudio.

I'd like to use the query parameter array in the where clause such as

```
STARTS_WITH(stringField, @paramArray[1])
AND STARTS_WITH(stringField, @paramArray[2])
AND STARTS_WITH(stringField, @paramArray[3])
…
```

For all elements of the `@paramArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT *, 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE (
  SELECT LOGICAL_AND(STARTS_WITH(param, stringField)) 
  FROM UNNEST(paramArray) AS param
)
```

so,  try below with @paramArray

```
SELECT *, 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE (
  SELECT LOGICAL_AND(STARTS_WITH(param, stringField)) 
  FROM UNNEST(@paramArray) AS param
)
```

Comment: excellent. Today i learned about LOGICAL_AND(). thank you so much.